# Variable names outside of structs in C

Tags: java, c, struct

I am reading a book called C for Java Programmers. 
It gives an example about nameless structs that I do not undestand.
It says that this is valid:

```
struct{
 int val1, val2;
 double val3;
} s1,s2;

  s1.val1 = 5;
  s2.val3 = 4.6;
```

If structs are similar to objects in Java, why can't I just say val1 = 5 and val2 = 4.6?
What is the point of s1 and s2?

Thanks

Comment: The code shown isn't valid C.

Comment: Structs are similar to _classes_.  The fact that it has no name makes no difference.

Comment: @alk It is a valid extract...

Comment: Well, think about it: when I say `val1 = 5` then whose `val1` did I just set, `s1`'s or `s2`'s? The member-names exist only inside the `struct`, similar to public fields in a Java class: when I'm outside the class and I want to set the value of a field I can only access the field via the instance.

Comment: @alk It is an excerpt out of the book. I am learning C now, so I assumed it was correct unless I don't understand what you mean by "valid C".

Comment: I don't think I'd ever actually use code like this, but it's valid. The code is functionally identical to declaring a structure type (with 3 elements, val1, val2, val3), then declaring two variables (s1, s2) of that structure type.

Comment: @Kninnug okay in JAVA if I said s1.val1 that would mean I was getting the val1 from the class s1. Okay so wait. Does that mean that s1 and s2 are just "instances" of the struct?

Comment: The OP's code isn't valid in terms of initialisation of obviously globally defined variables outside of any function.

Comment: @Blossom96 yes, just like with `struct`s that do have names. The only difference with nameless `struct`s is that `s1` and `s2` are now the *only* instances since you'd need the name of the `struct` to make more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`struct`s are similar to classes in the sense that you can view the members of a `struct` as public fields of a class. Because this struct has no name you only have the instances at the end of the `struct`'s declaration (`s1` and `s2`) because you'd need the `struct`'s name to make instances in other places.

In order to assign values to the members of the instances you need to access them through the instance (`s1` or `s2`).

You can compare it with the following Java scenario: you have a class with three public fields: `val1`, `val2` and `val3` and you have two instances of your class: `s1` and `s2`. In order to assign values to your instances you need to access the members through the instances:

```
s1.val1 = 5;
s2.val3 = 3.14;
```

The fact that the `struct` is nameless only means that you can't make other instances besides the ones at the end of the declaration, but has no effect on how you access the members of instances.

Comment: okay this is making sense. I just have one more question for clarification. You said "Because this struct has no name you only have the two instances s1 and s2." So if I added s3 and s4, then I would have four instances right? I guess I am just trying to make sure that you don't mean that you don't mean nameless structs can only have up to 2 instances.

Comment: @Blossom96 I suppose that was a bit ambiguously worded: you can indeed add more instances at the end of the declaration, so you could ineed add `s3` and `s4`. But with a nameless `struct` you can only make instances at the end of the `struct`'s declaration. Hope my edit clarified it.

Answer (score 1):

To initialise a `struct` variable you need to add an appropriate initialiser:

```
struct 
{
  int val1, val2;
  double val3;
} s1 =
{
  1, 2, 3.
};
```

Answer (score 1):

With this code you are creating (or instantiating in OO terms) two distinct nameless struct "objects". It is equivalent to:

```
struct name{
  int val1, val2;
  double val3;
}

struct name s1;
struct name s2;

s1.val1 = 5;
s2.val3 = 4.6;
```

if you want to give a name to the struct. Alternatively, you can create structures with initializers as alk suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Coming from java you can think of a C struct like a class without member functions:

```
//java:
class SomeData1 {
    public int val1;
    public int val2;
    public double val3;
}
```

So then you'd do:

```
// java:
SomeData1 s1= new SomeData1();
s1.val1 = 5;
```

In C you can use a struct like this by naming the structure:

```
// C:
typedef struct {
  int val1, val2;
  double val3;
} SomeData1;
```

Then you can set values:

```
// C:
SomeData1 s1;
s1.val1 = 5;
```

But it's also possible to use a structure "nameless" as you've seen in the example you posted:

```
struct{
 int val1, val2;
 double val3;
} s1,s2;
```

In this case you can still access the `s1` and `s2` structure's values:

```
s1.val1 = 5;
```

But you can't refer to the original structure... can't make additional instances (however many you declare initially, are the only ones you are going to get) of it. IMO the nameless structure isn't very useful.

Answer (score 0):

A `struct` in C is like an object in Java. But C has no classes, so there really isn't a need to name the type. I.e., you could say:

```
struct something {
   int a, b;
   double c;
};
```

and later say:

```
struct something s1, s2;

s1.a = 42;
s1.c = 2.14;
s2 = s1;
```

In the common case that you only define a few objects of that type, it may remain nameless (as in your snippet). The members `a`, `b`, `c` of `s1` and `s2` are different, just like if you have several objects of the same type in Java their members are separate values.

Answer (score 0):

That is a nice and elegant way of doing so:

```
struct s {
  int val1, val2;
  double val3;
};

struct s s1 = {
  .val1 = 1,
  .val3 = 3.1444
};
```

`s1.val2` will be set to `0` by the compiler. It is commonly used in [linux kernel source code](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/mach-mmp/aspenite.c#L185).

Answer (score 0):

By writing:

```
struct {
    int val1, val2;
    double val3;
} s1, s2;
```

inside, let's say, the `main` function; you declare two variables named `s1` and `s2`, which have the type `struct { int val1, val2; double val3; }` . This `struct { int val1, val2; double val3; }` is really similar to `int` or `char` or `float` , you can just think of it as a little longer type.

Now that you have the `s1` and `s2` , you can play with them, since they are variables, right? Well, if you had given a name to your `struct` then you'd have two ways of doing that, but since it doesn't have a name, you only have one way of doing it, and that is by changing individual contents that your `s1` and `s2` has. For example:

```
s1.val1 = 6;
s2.val3 = 5.2314;
```

If you had given a name to the `struct` , you'd have one another way of playing with its variables. Let's say you had given a name `abc` to it, like this:

```
struct abc {
    int val1, val2;
    double val3;
} s1, s2;
```

In that case, you can play around with the `s1` and `s2` as a whole, like this:

```
s1 = (struct abc) { 123, 234, 1.234 };
s2 = (struct abc) { 12, 34 };
```

For `s1` , it assigns `123` to `val1` , `234` to `val2` and `1.234` to `val3` . For `s2` , similar for first 2, and it assigns a `0` for the 3rd variable, because I've omitted that one.